# Google-geochart trigger 'Select' event on mouseover instead of click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

Is there a way to trigger the **select** events when i hover on a marker nstead of when i click on it?

i tried many things, the most logical way was this :

```
 $(document).on('mouseover','#myChart circle',function(evt) {

                 $(this).trigger('click');

                 });
```

I can do many diffent things on the element like changing the css of the svg but the click does not work.

Comment: $(document).on('mouseenter','#myChart circle',function(evt) {

                 $(this).trigger('click');

                 });

here is the demo
http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Comment: actually the click event is fired successfully but it does trigger the  select event of the chart